# Select Data based on Inner OR left join in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, inner-join

I have Table A and Table B
Where I want to select Data from Table A (EmpID)  with some join and Clauses.
Now I have to apply join with Table B (EMPID,NPINumber,NPIEndDate) all fileds are optional.

But Condition is that NPIEndDate is optional field in our database Like `NPIEndDate  is Null OR   NPIEndDate  > = CurrentDate`   Now write to query

1.Select Data from A & B Table  If NPINumber  is exists
2.Select Data from A & B Table  If NPIEndDate  is Null OR   NPIEndDate  > = CurrentDate

CurrentDate is : 27/06/2018

A table:

```
+-------+
| EmpId |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
+-------+
```

B table:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| EMPID | NPINumber | NPIEndDate |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     1 |      1001 | NULL       |
|     2 |      1234 | 27/04/2018 |
|     3 |     12345 | 27/06/2018 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Output

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| EMPID | NPINumber | NPIEndDate |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     1 |      1001 | NULL       |
|     3 |     12345 | 27/06/2018 |
|     4 |           |            | 
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data and the expected results.

Comment: Do you want two queries or just one to fetch your data?

Comment: single query only

Comment: Where is `StatelicenseEndDate` in your example?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initilization.  When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it says about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: What happened when you tried joining? Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
      a.EMPID,b.NPINumber,b.NPIEndDate 
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B 
          ON a.EMPID=b.EMPID
WHERE ISNULL(b.NPIEndDate,GETDATE())>='2018-06-27 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to What I understand

```
SELECT 
 DATA 
FROM
  A
INNER JOIN B
ON (A.EmpID = B.EMPID AND (NPIEndDate <> '' or NPIEndDate is not null)
```

**Update 2:** 
According to the data you provide

```
SELECT 
 DATA 
FROM
  A
INNER JOIN B
ON (A.EmpID = B.EMPID AND NPIEndDate >= CurrentDate AND (NPIEndDate = '' or NPIEndDate is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple join with some conditions in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.EMPID = B.EMPID
WHERE B.NPIEndDate IS NULL
      OR
      B.NPIEndDate >= '2018-06-27';
```

eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) A(EMPID) 
INNER JOIN 
(VALUES (1, 1001,NULL), (2, 1234,'2018-04-27'), (3, 12345,'2018-06-27'))B(EMPID, NPINumber, NPIEndDate)
ON A.EMPID = B.EMPID
WHERE B.NPIEndDate IS NULL
      OR
      B.NPIEndDate >= '2018-06-27'; --You can use GetDate() here if that what you mean by current date
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you need to do a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) between the tables where `EmpId` are the same than apply your filter.

```
SELECT 
  A.EmpID, B.NPINumber, B.NPIEndDate 
FROM 
  [Table A] A LEFT JOIN [Table B] B ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID 
WHERE 
  B.EmpID IS NULL 
  OR (NOT B.NPINumber IS NULL AND
  (B.[NPIEndDate] IS NULL OR B.[NPIEndDate] >= '2018/06/27'));
```

You can play with this query [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59777/2).

Comment: it will exclude those records from table A also where Emp Id of table A does not have NPIEndDate is null

Comment: I think this is what you need. Please see the answer above @SANDEEP.